# Object/JSON to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, json, xml, serialization

I'm working on application which generates dynamic expando objects whose could be converted to JSON using Newtonsoft.JSON. Expando objects could have different structure which could be projected to JSON. Is there some utility/library which allows me automatically generate SQL database table structure for given JSON object?  Do you know about any posibilities for generating SQL table structure programically and dynamically based on structure of a object?

Comment: This question is off topic to stackoverflow, but that doesn't mean it's not good, interesting, or answer worthy. Though I voted to close as off topic I did find the question interesting so I've tried the developr's best friend and came up with this link: https://blog.sqlizer.io/posts/convert-json-to-sql/

Comment: SQL server can create a database from a schema.  So getting a schema from the json is what you need.  msdn has a utiltiy that can create a schema from an xml.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe

Comment: How can you tell when the structure (schema) of the JSON is different from any existing tables? Otherwise, programmatically creating a SQL table on the fly is doable. Have you considered a NoSQL or Document database?